# $("p").each(function (){}) vs for( p in $("p") return different values for number of paragraphs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Running this jQuery code on the below HTML code return different results, I think they should be returning the same value.

**jQuery Code:**

```
var counter = 0;
$("p").each(function(){
            counter++;
});
console.log(counter); //returns 8

//-------------------------------------

counter = 0;
var ps = $("p");
for( var p in ps){
    counter++;
}
console.log(counter); //returns 158
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<li class="article-item">
    <p>--</p>
    <p> -- </p>
</li>
<li class="article-item">
    <p>--</p>
    <p> -- </p>
</li>

<li class="article-item">
    <p>--</p>
    <p> -- </p>
</li>
<li class="article-item">
    <p>--</p>
    <p> -- </p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop will iterate over the `enumerable properties` of an object up to the `end of the prototype chain`. So it cannot be used at this context. You can simply use `console.log($("p").length)` to find the count of elements grabbed with that selector.

The best example for understanding `for-in` loop would be,

```
var x = [1,2];
for(var prop in x){ console.log(prop) }
//This will print 0,1,length
```

Answer (score 1):

*Running this jQuery code on the below HTML code return different results, I think they should be returning the same value.*

No!

Although answer has been already answered but this.

`$('p')` is a jQuery object and it has specific length and some other properties added by the **jQuery** itself.

*The difference between native `document.querySelectorAll('p')` and `$('p')`.* Both returns a Array like collection but jQuery adds so many properties in the collection, you can see the difference in the snippet below:

```js
$('pre').eq(0).html(JSON.stringify(document.querySelectorAll('p'), 0, 3));
$('pre').eq(1).html(JSON.stringify($('p'), 0, 3));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

document.querySelectorAll('p'):
<pre></pre>

$('p'):
<pre></pre>

<ul>
  <li class="article-item">
    <p>--</p>
    <p>--</p>
  </li>
  <li class="article-item">
    <p>--</p>
    <p>--</p>
  </li>

  <li class="article-item">
    <p>--</p>
    <p>--</p>
  </li>
  <li class="article-item">
    <p>--</p>
    <p>--</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

So when you iterate with `for...in` loop it iterates over each property of `$('p')` object collection.